# Using the new Application Registration results in an error message on login

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a legacy B2C application that runs just fine. I decided to upgrade to the new 'experience' since the message said they're discontinuing the old legacy blade as of Nov-21. So I followed the instructions on this page:
[AAD B2C specifics](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AAD-B2C-specifics)
When I start up the application, I get this message:

[image]

Switching back to the legacy application results in a working login screen.

Comment: Compare the manifest of the old App Reg with the new App Reg for clues.

Answer (score 0):

•   Since your Azure AD B2C application is a *‘PublicClientApplication’*, it has the property of **‘UseCorporateNetwork’** which is a Boolean that enables the application to benefit from Integrated Windows Authentication and SSO as these are cross platform capabilities. Thus, set this property to *‘true’* in ***‘package.appxmanifest’*** by enabling the capabilities, viz., *Enterprise Authentication, Private Networks(Client & Server) and Shared User certificate*.

Also, as IWA is not enabled by default as applications requesting the above type of authentication require a higher level of verification to be accepted for social identities using MSAL .NET.

Kindly check the **‘RedirectURI’** of your new Azure AD B2C experience as it may get overridden by that in ***‘UserDetailsClient\App.cs’***. Hence, replace the *‘RedirectURI’* in your Azure AD B2C application by the one that is overridden in **‘UserDetailsClient\App.cs’** along with the ***msal://auth***. Maybe, this should resolve your issue. For more details, kindly refer to the below Github link below: -

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/issues/28

Answer (score 0):

To anyone running into a similar problem, I discovered two very interesting reasons for this problem:
In the legacy, you could share applications between your web API and your client. In the new workflow, you need one 'application' for your Web API, and a distinct 'application' for your clients.
This code seemed important to getting the new flow to work:

```
                this.PublicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(this.ClientId)
                    .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup(this.KeychainGroup)
                    .WithRedirectUri(this.RedirectUri)
                    .WithB2CAuthority($"https://{this.AuthorityHostName}/tfp/{this.Tenant}/{this.AuthorityPolicy}")
                    .Build();
```

The 'WithRedirectUri' got me past the original error posted above.